# Commenting on other's answers

Tags: discussion, etiquette

If I believe an answer to be (perhaps partially) incorrect, what should I do?

On other sites I would typically leave a comment explaining my thoughts, definitely so if I downvote the answer.  However, I was basically yelled at for doing so the other day.

This leaves me uncertain what the norm is on this site.

Comment: Who yelled at you? Without context it's hard to say what happened, but it sounds like you did the right general thing.

Comment: The norm is to just that, comment. I don't know why that person objected, but, in general, this is what we all do.

Comment: In the future, please also feel free to flag comments which are "yelling" or overly aggressive. While not everyone may agree on a "right" or "wrong" answer, we would much rather have constructive discussions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commenting is the norm. Yelling isn't.

I can see that the yelling got nuked by a fellow mod within less than 15 minutes of it getting posted. While your original comment is still there. That should be a pretty strong indication of what the norm here is.

Comment: From my POV it could have been removed due to the tone (which was pretty darn aggressive) rather than the substance.  I just wanted to be *really* sure about the standard here.  :)

Comment: There's no norm here. There're only double standards. But that's what all societies & communities are like: some folks are always more equal than others. Too many of the posters here seem to harbor a "my words are better than your words" mentality. Some harbor a "zero tolerance for anything **I** don't like" mentality. It's like the scene from _The Untouchables_ in which Ness throws Nitti off the roof after Nitti says: "You can't kill me. You're a cop." The "community" tolerates & protects some high-ranking users who're consistently nasty & condescending to non-native speakers of English. LMAO

Comment: @Bill: I'm probably at least as guilty as you of posting "intemperate, ill-advised" comments which may subsequently get deleted. But I think the mods do a good job of keeping things on an even keel without being too overbearing. It's not clear to me whether you do (or should!) include yourself in the "some high-ranking users" who are "tolerated and protected" (but my advice would be to "lighten up"! :)